# CSS z-index not applying to bootstrap popover on iPad

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Disclaimer:** I realize this is a bit of a long shot -- I can't provide a working jsfiddle nor can I provide a subset of code.

I'm putting the finishing touches on this site: http://dev.rebelsauce.co **`< Edit: link corrected`**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the url on an iPad
2. Tap the gear icon in the bottom right-hand corner
3. A bootstrap popover with "Logout" will appear behind the content. From the /store page, you can actually scroll past the end of the products and you will see it appear behind the `#page-products` div.

*Screenshot from desktop browser:*

[image: Screenshot from desktop browser]

On Desktop browsers (Chrome Win, Chrome OSX, Safari OSX) the z-index of the "Logout" popover works as expected - it's set to `position: relative; z-index: 300;`, and the `#page-products` and `.page-content` divs are both set to `postition: relative; z-index: 202 (and 203)`.

On an iPad however, the z-index isn't being respected. And unfortunately not being privy to any browser dev tools on mobile Safari, I can't play around with the CSS to determine what's causing it. I've tried setting all sorts of parent elements to `position: relative;` but to no avail.

I've spent a fair bit of time searching around for keywords like "boostrap popover z-index ipad", but still, no luck.

Comment: I"m looking at this in Chrome Win and I don't see a "gear icon"?

Comment: @ElGuapo bottom right-hand corner. I'll try and add a screenshot. OOPS! Wrong link. Link updated. Sorry.

Comment: whenever i run into z-index problems i like to draw out the relevant branches of the DOM tree and make sure z-index and position values are set appropriately all the way down.  It's easy to accidentally mess up stacking context without realizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `footer` z-index to 300 fixes it for me, although I don't know if doing that is undesirable for other reasons.

If you're on a Mac you actually **can** use the developer tools with iOS Safari.  Download xCode, run the iOS simulator, then navigate to your page.  Then, in OSX Safari, under the "Develop" menu choose the page in the "iPad Simulator" section.

Comment: Good tip on the iPad simulator -- will give that a shot if 300 doesn't fix it. Going to test now and will let you know!

Comment: Worked! Thanks a bunch. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.